# Using SQL to assign grades to marks from a lookup table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a query to give a grade to a percentage

I have a table of percentages per student per paper (StuID, pct, paperID) and a table of grade boundaries (paperID, minScore, maxScore, Grade)

the idea being to have a query that gives me student name and the grade that falls between min and max scores for the pct.

ridiculoulsy easy (lookup) in a spreadsheet, and seems to be ridiculously hard in SQL.  I am really trying to avoid exporting to Excel and calculating there, or hard coding the boundaries within a selection, but at the moment they seem to be my only options.

Any suggestions to keep this a)in SQL and b)as generalised as possible (ie I am going to want to reuse the query with different grade boundaries)

Due to (ridiculous) software constraints at work, I am limited to MS Access for my DB needs

thanks

Comment: would u mind sharing the spreadsheet u made with 1 or 2 examples. So we know what your grading looks like?

Comment: I am willing to provide help, I would just like to know what the grade in the grade boundaries table is doing. I am aware of the student pct being calculated between the min and max of the grade boundarie. But what is the grade col for in the boundaries table

Comment: Grade is effectively the output required from the gradeboundaries table, eg if pct is between 0.3 and 0.4 it should give a grade D and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be careful on how you handle the ranges. So check `>=` and `<` conditions and adjust to your case.

```
 SELECT S.StuID, S.paperID, S.pct, G.Grade
 FROM Student S
 JOIN Grades G
   ON S.grade >= G.minScore
  AND S.grade <  G.maxScore
```

Comment: I don't think this works in MS Access because of the inequality.  That portion may need to move to a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: That is spot on, I just could not get my head around how to make the join work, thanks